# C# Datagridview Mysql update

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to get my `DataGridView` updates back to the Mysql database, but it fails.

DataGridView loads my Database:

```
private void refreshbtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _sqlhost.Open();
    mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from ou", _sqlhost);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
    Tabel.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
    _sqlhost.Close();
}
```

That part of the code is working just fine. The whole database is loadet to the Datagridview.

It's here the problem comes!

```
private void Tabel_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable changes = ((DataTable)Tabel.DataSource).GetChanges();
    if (changes != null)
    {
        MySqlCommandBuilder mcb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);
        mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Update(changes);
        ((DataTable)Tabel.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

When I'm editing a Cell and hit the Enter button. This error comes:

> Additional information: Creating dynamic SQL for UpdateCommand is not
>   supported against a SelectCommand that do not return information about
>   a key column.

Comment: The error message is rather clear. Do add a key to the table or else you will always run into trouble. db tables without a key column are simly nonsense.

Comment: But a Key column dosen't fit to my database structure..

Comment: Sorry to be so blunt but then imo your data base design is flawed.

Comment: Ok, so i should alter the Table so it has a Primary key?

Comment: Yes, in my opion you should have a PK in __every__ table. Using a simple __autoincrement integer__ is the standard choice, but sometimes a natural key or a composite key are preferred. (These however are often releagted to secondary keys..)

Comment: Thanks TaW!! i Created a column called id and used autoincrement... that worked like a charm! :)